# Sending array as parameter in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql

I am trying to write a postgresql function that takes in an array and returns the users don't have id which belongs to the array. I wrote something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_api.get_user(banned_list TEXT[])
  RETURNS SETOF JSONB
AS $$
  SELECT to_jsonb(result)
  FROM (
    SELECT
           *
        FROM my_user.user_info
        WHERE my_user.user_info.user_id NOT IN (banned_list::TEXT[])

  ) AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL SECURITY DEFINER;
```

But it's throwing error like this

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist text <> text[]
LINE 24: ...     WHERE my_user.user_info.user_id NOT IN (no...
                                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried using CAST function too, doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `IN` operator on an array. You should use `ALL()` instead:

```
    WHERE my_user.user_info.user_id <> ALL(banned_list)
```

Note, that this will work well only if the type of `my_user.user_info.user_id` is text. If it is an integer column then you should use an array of integers as the argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_api.get_user(banned_list int[])
  RETURNS SETOF JSONB
AS $$
  SELECT to_jsonb(result)
  FROM (
    SELECT
           *
        FROM my_user.user_info
        WHERE my_user.user_info.user_id <> ALL(banned_list)

  ) AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL SECURITY DEFINER;
```